# smallest number of cells classified in a raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 and I ran con statement in the ModelBuilder within ArcGIS. I have an output raster (2m*2m) classified into four different classes. The raster has small pockets of 4 classes. I want to know what is the smallest number of cells that ModelBuilder has been able to categorize into a particular class.

Is there any specific command to figure this out or randomly we can say it can pick even a single cell that falls into a separate class?

Comment: Please clarify your question - I'm assuming this is Model Builder within the ArcGIS for Desktop software? Which ArcGIS version? What classification method was used? Generally, the question is awkwardly worded.

Comment: @ChrisStrother, I disagree, the Q is not asking how to calculate the total number of cells, but the number of cells of the same classification in individual groups/clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can use the Region Group tool to create unique groups of cells with the same classification value, you can then examine the attribute table to find groups with a small count.

You could do it in the Raster Calculator with one step:

```
Con(Lookup(RegionGroup("classraster"), "COUNT") < whatever_your_threshold_is, "classraster")
```

But I also suggest you have a read of this [help topic](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/generalization-of-classified-raster-imagery.htm) which discusses the process of cleaning up a classified image using the following methods:

- Removing misclassified cells with Majority Filter
- Smoothing zones with Boundary Clean
- Identifying clusters with Region Group
- Remove areas smaller than threshold